# What is the general formula for calculating the probability of selecting at least N white balls...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the general formula for calculating the probability of selecting at least N white balls when randomly selecting M balls without replacement from a bag containing Q white balls and R black balls?

This is one of those problems that I should probably remember from school but I've searched around a little and while I can find a few worked examples. For some reason they seem to almost all give real, small-number workthroughs with shortcuts that only work when N and M are small rather than general formula.

For context, I realized that a problem that a co-worker was trying to solve through approximation simplified to the above problem where (approx)

N=20
M=80
Q=1000
R=13000

Or other similar largish numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{k=N}^{\min(M,Q)}\frac{\binom{Q}{k}\cdot\binom{R}{M-k}}{\binom{Q+R}{M}}$$

Comment: Perfect!  thanks for the quick reply. Converted to syntax for wolfram alpha:

sum ((DFBC(1000, k)*(DFBC(13000, 80-k)))/(DFBC(1000+13000, 80))), k=20 to 80

Comment: @Murphy: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

For large numbers, you should use the normal approximation.  The expected number of white balls to draw is $\frac {MQ}{Q+R}=\mu$, which is the mean of your distribution.  The standard distribution is $\sqrt{Mpq}$ where $p=\frac Q{Q+R}$ is the probability of a white ball and $q=1-p=\frac R{Q+R}$ is the probability of a black ball, so $\sigma= \frac {\sqrt{MQR}}{Q+R}$  Figure out the number of standard deviations high you need to be or how many you can afford to be low.  You can use these with a table of the cumulative normal distribution to find the probability you seek.

Comment: Is this because an exact combinatorical expression, like Barak's, is practical not to evaluate (large numbers showing up)?

Comment: I'd love to mark both of these as answers since they're both useful, barak's for being exact and this answer for being the most practical to implement in R. Thanks so much for the quick and clear answers

Comment: You can avoid the large numbers by using Stirling's approximation. Which you want to use depends on your needs. For large numbers, the normal approximation is very accurate